# Check if User is idle - server side vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, events

I wish to build a vb.net web page that has some event - on the server side,

That will check if the user is IDLE - no keyboard use on the page or mouse move/press

I know that there is a simple way to do so in jquery but for security matters i need this event to happened on the server, so for example i could notify some service every 30 seconds if the user is "idle" or "alive"

EDIT:

As i understand from the comments, there is no way for the server side to know this on its own since its a client event.

So what would be the most secure way to pass this ? so a user could not add a client script that would "fake" a live user that is actually idle ,

Is There such way ?

Comment: All of those events occur in the client, so you are going to need javascript somehow to tell the server a given event has occured.

Comment: Unless you're measuring from the last page request, the client-side code would need to tell the server-side code what's happening in the browser.  (keyboard usage or mouse move/press)  There's no way for the server-side code to know this on its own.

Comment: But the keyboard or mouse event did not happen on the server.

Answer (score -1):

Simple approach:
Track the users last request made and record the time stamp, If the user makes any key strokes also update the time stamp by sending the request to the server. Once you have the time stamp you can check if the user is no longer active.

Advanced approach:
I am assuming this is a ASP.Net application you can also track the user session and check activity.

Comment: "if the user makes any key strokes also update the time stamp by sending the request to the server" -> that is a client side event that i wish to avoid... and tracking the session wont indicate keyboard/mouse events...

Comment: The server does not know if the user is doing anything with the keyboard or the mouse unless you use javascript to track that. There is no way around this. The server interprets user requests it does not know what the user is doing only the browser has access to this information.